# Calculate total time with in/out data using C#

Tags: c#

How to write a C# code to calculate total InTime in Office with multiple in/out times given for a specific person on one particular day.I have a dropdown for selecting a person name and one calendar to select date on which I need to get the total InTime of an employee.

Data is like given below in an excel sheet xyz.:

```
 **Date          Event Description   Item Description**
12/21/2012 1:51 Exit granted    Ban Swapnil
12/21/2012 2:45 Entry granted   Ban Swapnil
12/21/2012 8:12 Exit granted    Ban Swapnil
12/25/2012 22:44    Entry granted   Ban Swapnil
12/26/2012 0:59 Exit granted    Ban Swapnil
12/26/2012 1:34 Entry granted   Ban Swapnil
12/26/2012 8:15 Exit granted    Ban Swapnil
12/26/2012 22:05    Entry granted   Ban Swapnil
12/26/2012 23:46    Exit granted    Ban Swapnil
12/21/2012 1:24 Exit granted    Bandel Ashish Chander
12/21/2012 15:23    Entry granted   Bandel Ashish Chander
12/21/2012 15:34    Exit granted    Bandel Ashish Chander
12/21/2012 15:51    Entry granted   Bandel Ashish Chander
12/21/2012 16:06    Exit granted    Bandel Ashish Chander
12/21/2012 16:29    Entry granted   Bandel Ashish Chander
12/21/2012 17:56    Exit granted    Bandel Ashish Chander
12/21/2012 18:32    Entry granted   Bandel Ashish Chander
12/21/2012 19:03    Exit granted    Bandel Ashish Chander
12/21/2012 19:37    Entry granted   Bandel Ashish Chander
12/21/2012 21:40    Exit granted    Bandel Ashish Chander
12/21/2012 21:50    Entry granted   Bandel Ashish Chander
12/21/2012 23:01    Exit granted    Bandel Ashish Chander
12/24/2012 13:39    Entry granted   Bandel Ashish Chander
12/24/2012 13:41    Exit granted    Bandel Ashish Chander
12/24/2012 14:52    Entry granted   Bandel Ashish Chander
12/24/2012 15:54    Exit granted    Bandel Ashish Chander
12/24/2012 16:41    Entry granted   Bandel Ashish Chander
12/24/2012 18:31    Exit granted    Bandel Ashish Chander
12/24/2012 22:07    Entry granted   Bandel Ashish Chander
12/24/2012 23:00    Exit granted    Bandel Ashish Chander
12/25/2012 14:00    Entry granted   Bandel Ashish Chander
12/25/2012 14:02    Exit granted    Bandel Ashish Chander
12/25/2012 14:48    Entry granted   Bandel Ashish Chander
12/25/2012 18:45    Exit granted    Bandel Ashish Chander
12/26/2012 13:14    Entry granted   Bandel Ashish Chander
12/26/2012 13:29    Exit granted    Bandel Ashish Chander
12/26/2012 14:33    Entry granted   Bandel Ashish Chander
12/26/2012 17:45    Exit granted    Bandel Ashish Chander
```

Comment: You cant shop code at SO.. Tell us where you're stuck. Read http://stackoverflow.com/faq first

Comment: I don't see anything in your data that distinguishes between "in" time and "out" time?

Comment: @wageoghe: Entry versus Exit granted?

Comment: @comecme Oh.  When I made my comment the data example had been edited (from its original form) such that the "Entry granted/Exit granted" information was removed.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty simple. You're probably just not thinking it through. You can get the difference between two dates as a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx). This means you can do `date1 - date2` and get a TimeSpan structure which will give you number of hours/mins/seconds.

Now, say you have a bunch of **in** and **out** times for a given user, you need a List of of a **pair of in and out times**. A [2-tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx) is perfect for the job, so you'll have a list of 2-tuples.

Given a map of in/out time pairs you can just total up the TimeSpans. Here is an example:

*(Note your data doesn't make sense to me, but if you can generate the below list from your data then the problem statement you have is solved.)*

```
List<Tuple<DateTime,DateTime>> lstForOnePerson = ..
int totalHours = 0;
foreach(var tup in lstForOnePerson)
{
 //this is assuming the first item in the tuple is IN time and the second is OUT
 TimeSpan tm = tup.Item2 - tup.Item1;
 totalHours += tm.TotalHours;
}
```

Comment: +1 Awesome example `Gideon` but if the OP can't present a meaningful example I can't expect him to understand what a `Tuple` is let alone your awesome example..

Comment: Adjacent data in datetime format are alternatively In Time and exit time.I  am completely new in this field of coding and trying to get out of this point of complexity...

Comment: for (DateTime startTime = selectedDate; startTime != startTime.AddMinutes(1439); startTime.AddMinutes(1))
                        {
                            DateTime firstTime = DateTime.Parse(TxtbDate.Text);
                            DateTime nextTime = DateTime.Parse(dt.Rows[Number+1]["Date"].ToString());
                            string diffTime = nextTime.Subtract(firstTime).ToString();
                            //TxtbInTime.Text = diffTime.ToString();
                        }

Comment: I was trying my luck in that way. :-(